# How to read a txt file in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried this code to load and read a txt file. But it can't read file and returns "Couldn't read file" message.

```
Future<String> _read() async {
  String text;
    try {
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final file = File('${directory.path}/table.txt');
      text = await file.readAsString();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Couldn't read file");
    }
    return text;
  }
```

I set my txt file in a folder(data) in the directory of the project.I tried it with `final file = File('${directory.path}/data/table.txt');` too. This is my "pubspec.yaml" file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - data/table.txt
```

I get this error:

```
I/flutter ( 2067): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2067): The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
I/flutter ( 2067): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 235 pos 15: 'data != null': is not
I/flutter ( 2067): true.
I/flutter ( 2067): 
I/flutter ( 2067): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter ( 2067): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter ( 2067): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter ( 2067):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 2067): 
I/flutter ( 2067): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 2067): #2      new Text 
package:flutter/…/widgets/text.dart:235
I/flutter ( 2067): #3      MyApp.build 
package:hello_flutter/main.dart:90
I/flutter ( 2067): #4      StatelessElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3774
I/flutter ( 2067): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3721
I/flutter ( 2067): #6      Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3547
I/flutter ( 2067): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2286
I/flutter ( 2067): #8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:676
I/flutter ( 2067): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback 
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:219
I/flutter ( 2067): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:990
I/flutter ( 2067): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:930
I/flutter ( 2067): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:751
I/flutter ( 2067): #14     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 2067): #15     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 2067): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_pat
ch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter ( 2067): (elided 3 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 2067): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2067): Couldn't read file
I/flutter ( 2067): null
Reloaded 1 of 420 libraries in ۱٬۱۰۴ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the full path in `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/data/table.txt
```

you should create an `assets` folder inside your main project directory where folders such as : lib , build and IOS reside and put your `data` directory inside it, then add the aforementioned lines and run the command `flutter packages get` and after completion it will work fine.

Comment: I get this problem: "The asset assets/data/table.txt does not exist."

Comment: is the directory `data` placed directly inside your assets folder ?

Comment: I haven't assets folder in my project directory. I have this folders: (.idea _ android _ duild  _ ios _ lib _ test) and added <data> folder to it.

Comment: apply what I mentioned in the edited answer and tell me about the result

Comment: added it to my question.